# Mail not sent automatically with cron

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

I am facing a problem with custom email. Email does not sent automatically according to its schedule.

Cron is working fine. I have debug code using `Mage::log()`. I am getting each log before **sendTransactional** function after that log is not working.

However its working fine with Aoe_schedule when I execute cron forcefully.

But Its not working automatically..

So the code is correct. Problem is with automatic cron execution.

Comment: Can you share your config.xml file, where is that cron job is defined?

Comment: <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <namespace_test_cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 10 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>test/observer::run</model>
                </run>
            </namespace_test_cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

Comment: So, your job should be executed on 00:10 every day, right?

Comment: Yes, However I am scheduling with Aoe_schedule for testing. so It should execute in next schedule. Cron is working fine as I told log is generating at the time cron execute. But It halt after sendTransactional function.

Comment: You may have a syntax error or something like that in one of the email templates you are trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a crontab file

**in server cmd**

```
crontab -e
```

**in open window**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=your email for error message
```

*/5 * * * * full path to your site `cron.sh` file(example: `/home/username/www/public_html/cron.sh`)

this is will execute your `cron.sh` every 5 minutes and Aoe_Sheduler dosen't write a warning about heartbeat